# Confine text to main part of webpage

Tags: html, css, sections

I am trying to setup a simple webpage with three sections which i setup like this.

```
.top 
     {
     position:absolute;
     left:0; right:0;
     height: 80px;
     }

     .left 
     {
     position:absolute;
     left:0; top:80px; bottom: 0;
     width: 300px;
     }

     .main 
     {
     margin-left: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     left:300px; top:80px; right:0; bottom:0;
     }
```

However, the problem occurs when I first try to put text in the top, and then when I try to put text in the main section it appears on top of the text in the top area as demonstrated in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2WZ2S/.  I would like someone to suggest code to fix this problem.

Comment: and your output should look like...?

Comment: with the content in the "main section" constrained to the boundaries of the main section, and the content of the "top section" constrained to the boundaries of the top section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your .main top margin is not large enough try 
`.main 
     {
     margin-left: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     left:300px; top:220px; right:0; bottom:0;
     }`